# ZSH distorts in my VS code terminal and shows characters with long spaces

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, fonts, oh-my-zsh

I enabled zsh on my vs code terminal but it displays like this:

[image]

here is my settings.json:
[image]

how can I fix it?

Comment: I guess you are missing fonts for vs code terminal
Just add this setting to your vscode settings.json
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "<Font Family>",

Comment: @Bhumit070 I've just edited my question.

Comment: Are you still facing the same error ? which theme you are using ?

Comment: yes,  the [google light](https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term/#/google-light) theme

Comment: not able to reproduce the error please make sure all fonts are installed in system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu 20.04 none of the stuff in the answers worked for me, it kept complaining about with the message:

The terminal only supports monospace fonts.

So I dig a bit and this is my solution:

No need to add extra fonts in Ubuntu 20.04 to fix this, we just need to add the missing powerline fonts inside vscode to display the symbols correctly.

So I just added to my settings and rebooted the program:

```json
{
    ...
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "monospace, PowerlineSymbols",
    ...
}
```

And everything was nice and smooth and I could see my VSCode terminal with powerline just like the regular OS terminal.